# How to use wait_for() in dicord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am working on a music bot for discord. I want to use `bot.wait_for()` to wait until `voice.stop()`. i.e i want the bot to wait until the playback is stopped. I do not want to use the command  `voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio), after=lambda e: some_commmand_here)` as this command executes a command after the playback is finished. However I am trying to make the bot wait until the playback is finished and then do something. I tried `bot.wait_for(voice.stop())` which turned out to be wrong. Any help? If `bot.wait_for()` cannot do the job, any alternative command that waits until the playback is finished is fine with me.

Comment: You could potentially use the ```on_voice_state_update()``` event.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only use [these](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-api-events) events without `on_` prefix for `wait_for`. So there is only one event related to voice and that is [on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update). So it's not possible to do with api unless you make it yourself.

Comment: As i said, any other alternative way is fine. Can you suggest me one?

Comment: Maybe you can check the lenght of the song, then with `time` or `datetime` module, you can check if the song is over.

Comment: This was possible only if I had not made a function to pause the song. So if the use pauses the song, then the length of the song will not help me

Comment: Is there a function like `voice.stop()`?

Comment: And is there a function like `is_voice_stop`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220706/discussion-between-sathvik-k-s-and-nurqm).